# Primefaces: Action of remoteCommand not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to do something in the backend when the user clicks a link in my dataTable. For that, I use a remoteCommand that is definetly being called, however, its action is not. My code looks like this:

.xhtml:

```
    <p:dataTable id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
                 widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.id}"
                 var="doc"
                 editable="true"
                 rowKey="#{doc.id}"
                 emptyMessage="#{msgs.dataTable_emptyMessage}"
                 value="#{cc.attrs.data}">

    ....

        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <a href="#{documentService.prepareDokumentURLForOpen(doc.name)}"
                           target="#{documentService.getDokumentTarget(doc.name())}"
                           title="#{doc.name}" onclick="highlightDocument(); alert('onclick triggered');">#{doc.name}

                        </a>
                        <p:remoteCommand name="highlightDocument" action="#{doc.highlight()}" oncomplete="alert('complete triggered')" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>

    ....

    </p:dataTable>
```

The `doc` referenced in the dataTable is a is some POJO with the `highlight()` function called above.
document.java:

```
public void highlight() {
    System.out.println("highlight called");
}
```

When I run this code, I get both `'onclick triggered'` and `'complete triggered'` , so I know the remoteCommand is being called. However, the `highlight()` function isn't called.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any errors in your browser's JavaScript console? You should not put `p:remoteCommand` in a data table, as it is repeating. Place it outside of the data table and make sure it's placed in a form.

See also [mcve].

Comment: There are so many things things that can cause these problems. Is `p:remoteCommand` within a form? Is everything enclosed in a `h:body`. Is your backing bean correctly defined?

Plus, there is a myriad of other things that can cause issues. You need to supply a [mcve].